# HTML / Texts rendering difference same sizes + factor / zoom

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering, difference

I created a JSFiddle to help you guys understand what my problem is: https://jsfiddle.net/7355kq0n/2/ (better if you make the HTML side wider)

```
<div id="el1" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="el2" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="el3" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="el4" contenteditable="true"></div>


var els, style, text;

style = { "height": 103.23, "width": 90.41, "fontSize": 9.32 };
els = [{
  element: document.querySelector("#el1"),
  scale: 1
}, {
  element: document.querySelector("#el2"),
  scale: 1.732
}, {
  element: document.querySelector("#el3"),
  scale: 2.3
}, {
  element: document.querySelector("#el4"),
  scale: 4.324
}];
text = "Sed commodo neque quis vulputate porttitor. Quisque pulvinar ullamcorper bibendum. Fusce dignissim vestibulum massa, eget blandit nunc tempor at. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla accumsan nunc ac enim vehicula, ac tristique augue congue. Integer a dictum libero. Proin semper mattis luctus. In gravida nisi et leo venenatis fringilla. Quisque ut euismod lorem. Mauris vitae vestibulum ligula. Suspendisse tristique augue placerat augue mollis bibendum.";

for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
    var el = els[i];

  el.element.innerHTML = text;

  for (attr in style) {
    el.element.style[attr] = (style[attr] * el.scale) + "px";
  };
}
```

As you can quickly see, keeping the same sizes (width, height, fontSize) for HTML elements then just applying a zoom factor on them, creates different rendering results ... Text will not be cut at the same place depending on the zoom.

I come to this problem because of the same problem we get at work in an App, and we are wondering what is making this problem happen (our code, environment, resets, ...) but this simple test make me believe we are just blocked by browser capacity ...

Do I miss something? Is it a browser issue or browser limit? Is there a fix or improvement for this kind of stuff? :)

Comment: You mean that the blocks don't all wrap on the same words? Well, that's just rounding errors. Sizes can only be set in whole pixels, so the font size for the first one will be 9px and the width 90px, making the width exactly 10em. For the second one, the width is 9.8125em. Etc.

Comment: Yep, well I hoped that was something else but rounded pixels rendering seem legit ... :/

Comment: However is there any way to get a proper scaling rendering? Maybe something as stupid as round all values then scale.

But if the scale/zoom is a float and we round the result too, there will be an other rendering issue, right? Because there will be sometimes 1 round, sometimes 2, and so not the exact same ratio I guess ...

Comment: One improvement would be to round the font size to whole pixels, and to use a size in `em` for the height and width. That way, the differences are not as bad. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/7355kq0n/3/ I haven't been able to eradicate all the differences though; my fiddle now is ok if you set the font to 'Times', but there are still mismatches with 'Arial'.

Comment: You could look into `transform:scale(...)` but I'm not sure how many browsers you want to support.

Comment: Yeah I looked at transform scale quickly, it seems to reduce differences quite a lot but it would slow our app and create positioning issues too (to keep it simple).
About sizes in em and rounded font sizes, it would be complicated because to make it simple: it implies a graphic design created on Indesign (pt) then exported as XML (mm) then editable (text, font size, font family, ...) as HTML (px) then generated as images and generated as a PDF too. Customers need exactly the same rendering in each of these steps, of course :D
Thank you! That makes me happy to see someone is trying to help :)

Comment: But I don't have any further ideas. Unless you're willing to render stuff at a large size and then scale the resulting bitmap down, I don't know of a foolproof way to do what you want.